# Hoeffding's inequality with a probabilistic bound?

Tags: inequality

Hoeffding's inequality states that:

Let $\mathbf{X}_1, \dots, \mathbf{X}_n$ be independent random variables, such that $\mathbf{X}_i \in [a_i, b_i]$ with probability one. Let $\mathbf{S}_n$ be $\sum_i^n\mathbf{X}_i$. Then for any $t>0$
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\mathbf{S}_n-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{S}_n]|\geq t) \leq 2\exp(-\dfrac{2t^2}{\sum_i^n(b_i-a_i)^2})
$$

Now, I wonder if this has any variant for the case like $\mathbf{X}_i \in [a_i, b_i]$ with probability $p_i$? Is there any theorems related? What terminologies should I use to google these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most general case where the distribution of $X_i$ can be *anything* when outside of $[a_i, b_i]$, there can be no result - we can take a mixture of the uniform distribution on $[a, b]$ with probability $p$ and the Cauchy distribution with probability $1-p$. Just like the Cauchy distribution itself, this mixture distribution will *also* have undefined mean and variance, and there will be little we can say about it.

However, if we place restrictions on what can happen outside of the interval $[a, b]$ the situation is not so bad! There is a well-known extension of Hoeffding's inequality where requirement that $X_i$ are bounded is relaxed and $X_i$ is only required to be [sub-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_distribution). Sub-Gaussian distributions have "thin tails" that decay rapidly relative to the Gaussian distribution:

$$ \forall i, P(|X_i|\geq t)\leq 2e^{-ct^2} \tag{1}$$

Then we can have a result very similar to Hoeffding's inequality. See Theorem 2.6.2 of *High Dimensional Probablity* by Vershynin, for instance:

$$ P(S \geq t) \leq 2 \exp \Bigg( -\frac{ct^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n ||X_i||^2_{\psi_2}} \Bigg) \tag{2}$$.

Where the notation $||X||_{\psi_2}$ refers to the "sub-Gaussian norm" defined in the same book.

For the case where $X$ is unbounded and no particular restriction is placed on the tails, I'm not aware of any result better than [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality). Chebyshev's inequality works for any distribution with finite mean and variance so is very general. Let $\mu = \mathbb{E}[S] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[ X_i ]$ and $\sigma^2 = \mathrm{Var}[S] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var}[ X_i] $. Then the Chebyshev bound is:

$$ P(|S-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2} \tag{3} $$

Which we could also write in the same form as the other theorems but substituting $t = k\sigma$:

$$ P(|S-\mu|\geq t) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{t^2} \tag{4} $$

As for other references, definitely try Vershynin's book. There was also a [Google hit](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10986-008-9007-7) for "unbounded Hoeffding inequality" but I haven't read it.

Comment: Hey @olooney ! I was wondering if you can make a statement using Hoeffding conditioned on the event that x_i \in [a,b] with probability 1-\delta_1 ? The Hoeffding bound will hold with  probability (1-\delta_1)(1-\delta_2) with \delta_2 being the failure probability of the Hoeffding bound.